# Выводятся не все элементы словаря - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Имеется следующий код:

```
dist = {'1': '1','2': '2','3': '3','4': '4','5': '5','6': '6'}

f_key, f_value = None, None
for key, value in dist.items():
    if f_key and f_value: 
       print('  %s  >  %s' % (f_value,f_key))
    f_key, f_value = key, value
```

выводится только 5 позиций из 6 имеющихся:

```
  1  >  1
  2  >  2
  3  >  3
  4  >  4
  5  >  5
```

Однако при проверке выводятся все элементы словаря

```
print(dist.items())
```

или

```
print(dist)
```

Вывод полный

```
dict_items([('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6')])

{'1': '1', '2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4', '5': '5', '6': '6'}
```

В чем заключается моя ошибка и как вывести все имеющиеся позиции?

Comment: В том, что f_key и f_value у вас изначально None, проверка if не проходит и логично что ничего не печатается до тех пор, пока вы значение f_key и f_value не замените

Comment: Спасибо, увидел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dist = {'1': '1','2': '2','3': '3','4': '4','5': '5','6': '6'}

f_key, f_value = None, None
for key, value in dist.items():
    f_key, f_value = key, value
    if f_key and f_value: 
       print('  %s  >  %s' % (f_value,f_key))
```

Как-то так

Answer (score 2):

А почему вы думаете, что при первой итерации цикла должно что-то выводиться? У вас условие не выполняется, поэтому то, что в блоке `if` не выполняется

Comment: Если условие убрать совсем, вывод останется таким же
Пользователь выше, указал на имеющуюся ошибку. Это решает проблему

Comment: @Mons почему тогда у меня без условия вывод меняется, мы на разных языках пишем? =)

Comment: Я понял о чем вы, внес правки. Спасибо что обратили внимание. Взгляд замылился уже.